# Place the QED symbol for a proof that ends with a figure on the same line of the figure caption

Tags: captions, amsthm, amssymb, proof-package, qed

I have a figure at the end of a `proof` environment (see MWE below). I would like to have the QED symbol that ends the proof on the same line of the figure caption. Placing `\qedhere` after or inside `\caption` did not do it. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        \lipsum[1]
        \begin{figure}[h]
            \centering
            %\includegraphics{...}
            \caption{Figure caption.} \qedhere
        \end{figure}
    \end{proof} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A figure is a float, and it may not go where you input it.  Using `\inputgraphic` and `\captionof` is much more reliable in this department.  Even so, `\qedhere isn't going to work by itself, but a negative `\vspace` before the `\end{proof}` should work.  I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate Beeton's comment:

Note that the caption package adds an additonal `\dp\strutbox` to the bottom baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        \lipsum[1]
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.9\textwidth}
            \centering
            %\includegraphics{...}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure caption.}%\vspace{-\dp\strutbox}
        \end{minipage}%\llap{\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.5pt}}% show baseline
    \end{proof} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @JohnKormylo, for the answer. The only thing is that the figure is not centered as within the `figure` environment. I am wondering if there is any solution to fix that.

Comment: @AEW - One should also center the minipage, since I had to leave extra room for the QED.